# Aframe exitVR() without hmdEnabled results in unexpected z-axis rotation

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, aframe

**Issue**

When triggering `exitVR()` the rotation of the `camera` component gains unexpected z-axis when the expected value is 0. The camera becomes tilted or skewed.

**Before enterVR() & exitVR()**

[image]

*After exitVR()*

[image]

```
<a-entity id="rig" position="0 1.6 0">
  <a-entity
    id="camera"
    camera
    look-controls="enabled: true; hmdEnabled: false; touchEnabled: true;">
  </a-entity>
</a-entity>
```

According to the Aframe doc:

> When exiting VR, the camera will restore its rotation to its rotation before it entered VR. This is so when we exit VR, the rotation of the camera is back to normal for a desktop screen.

Comment: Can you provide info about device, headset and browser used. Also link to full test case to reproduce. https://glitch.com/~aframe is a good option

Comment: I am not sure I can easily create a an example to reproduce. The project is built in Angular.